# Does mutex have scope?

Tags: c++, mutex

Does `std::mutex` have scope? I know in JAVA we can use `{}` to limit the lock in scope to release the lock as soon as possible. If we can do the same thing in c++ ?

```
void func() {
  // some code
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
  }
  // some code
}
```

additional, when did the mutex work? Does the lock work as soon as it enters the function, or does it execute until the current line is locked? Does the compiler have an impact on code optimization?

```
void func() {
  // some code
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);   // mutex work here or as soon as it enters the function
  // some code
}
```

Comment: All objects created on the stack has scope in `c++`. `std::lock_guard` is a separate object to the mutex that has it's own scope. It's only job it to lock the mutex when it's created and unlock the mutex when it's destroyed.

Comment: It is the `std::lock_guard` that has scope here, not the `std:mutex`, which would have to have global/static scope for this code to succeed.

Comment: So it worked until run the std::lock_guard line. and `{}` doesn't affect its function? It must be released when the function ends or release it actively?

Comment: I don't know what 'it' refers to, but if you mean the `std::lock_guard`, it didn't *exist* until the scope was entered, and it is certainly destroyed when the scope is exited. All this is documented.

Comment: Names have scope. Objects have lifetimes.

Comment: @molbdnilo The lifetime of an object declared by value like this in a scope is identical to its lexical scope. This is the whole point. Don't add to the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help, I finally found the answer. **Read the source code, then no magic**. Below is lock_guard's source code.

```
   template<typename _Mutex>
     class lock_guard
     {
     public:
       typedef _Mutex mutex_type;
 
       explicit lock_guard(mutex_type& __m) : _M_device(__m)
       { _M_device.lock(); }
 
       lock_guard(mutex_type& __m, adopt_lock_t) noexcept : _M_device(__m)
       { } // calling thread owns mutex
 
       ~lock_guard()
       { _M_device.unlock(); }
 
       lock_guard(const lock_guard&) = delete;
       lock_guard& operator=(const lock_guard&) = delete;
 
     private:
       mutex_type&  _M_device;
     };
```

"lock_guard" acquires the lock when it is created, and releases the lock when it is destroyed.
It helps us not to forget to release the lock.
Even when the program fails, the destructor is called to release the lock.